# getting issue while building android os pie

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

I have done `make clean` and after that `make -j7` but got this build issue. Please help

````
[61/62] glob vendor/mediatek/proprietary_mt8168/frameworks/ml/nn/tflite/tensorflow/contrib/lite/tflite_static.bp
[113/113] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build out/soong/build.ninja
FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja 
out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list -b out/soong -n out -d out/soong/build.ninja.d -o out/soong/build.ninja Android.bp
error: external/doclava/bin/Android.bp:15:1: module "droiddoc-templates-sdk" already defined
       external/doclava/Android.bp:15:1 <-- previous definition here
error: external/doclava/bin/Android.bp:20:1: module "doclava" already defined
       external/doclava/Android.bp:20:1 <-- previous definition here
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
21:42:48 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1```
````

Answer (score 1):

delete this folder:

*external/doclava/bin*

and re-run the build